# How to cope with extraneous characters left on the input stream? (cin skipped)

Tags: c++, input

Sorry for the noobish question here, but I am just learning C++ and I am looking for the standard way of dealing with this problem.  I am using VS2005.

Given a program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( )
{
    while ( true )
    {       
        cout << "enter anything but an integer and watch me loop." << endl;     
        int i;
        cin >> i;               
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you enter anything but an integer the program will never allow you to enter anything again.  Now, I realize that this is because there is input left on the stream after the format fails, so each call to cin << i just reads up to the next end line (I think).  How do you guys clear out the stream or deal with this problem?  It must be pretty common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I found the answer.  The answer is...

Don't do this.  Do not mix formatted and unformatted input using operator >>.  Here is a good article on the subject:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046/

Basically, the code changes to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stream>

using namespace std;

int main( )
{
    while ( true )
    {           
        cout << "enter anything but an integer and watch me loop." << endl;     
        string input;
        getline( cin, input );
        int i;
        stringstream stream( input );
        if ( stream >> i ) break;                       
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could indeed have made i into a string and convert that.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for the canonical way to guard against bad input in C++.  This seems to be it.

Comment: go ahead and accept the answer! And remove the downvotes, the answers are not actually wrong (anymore ;-)). But this one, although the code is ugly, works better and more professionally. good find!

Comment: I have to wait 2 days before I can accept it.  Thanks again (and yes, darn ugly code)

Comment: weird, people placing a downvote, should either upvote the right answer or supply a better one if they know better. At least add a comment...sheesh

Comment: it should be `#include <sstream>`

Answer (score 2):

surround the cin call with an if.

The cin will return false if wrong data is read.

so:

```
if (!cin >> i) {
  cin.clear();
  cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
  cout << "Haha, your looping efforts have been thwarted dear sir\n";
}
```

cin.flush() should do the trick (according to cppreference.com) but not on VS apparently.

cin.clear() resets all flags to a good state.
cin.ignore with a large number and until '\n' should work.

Comment: It returns a stream, which can be converted to a void*, which can be converted to true or false, but still I have to ask how to cope?  Sure, I can detect the bad input, but then what?  It is still on the stream

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using VS2005

Comment: Well, I am using iostream, but cin is an istream

Comment: Yeah... that doesn't work, I've tried it.  Are you testing this stuff?

Comment: sorry, can't at this time... So i'm using my google fu... add the cin.clear, and the consensus on the web is that it does the job.

Comment: After the last edit, yes, it does, but it is still not the proper way to do it.  I found a better answer.

Comment: Honestly, while I do appreciate the effort, it is not the best way to handle the situation.

Comment: agreed, your answer is better

Comment: Rather that INT_MAX I would use 'std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');'

Answer (score 0):

cin.ignore(int num_bytes_to_ignore); will do it.

You can also use stdio, fflush(fd); where fd is one of stdout,stderr,stdin.

Comment: I don't see an "flush" member function, and calling ignore before the cin >> i doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: I may just be using ignore( ) incorrectly, so an example would be nice.

Comment: Sorry, cin.flush doesn't exist indeed, fflush(stdin) is the one you want.

Comment: I tried adding fflush( stdin ) before the call to cin and it still loops. There must be a standard way of dealing with formatted input, right?

Comment: fflush is undefined behavior on input stream.