# Determine how many characters are given in cin?

Tags: c++, input, cin

Suppose i have written:

```
    ...
    char c;
    while(condition){
       cin>>c;
       //do stuff
       ...
    }
...
```

If `2` characters are give in cin, the next cin will take the second character without me giving any. So, i tried this:

```
...
char c;
while(condition){
   cin<<c
   //do stuff
   ...
   cin.ignore("999 \n");
}
...
```

In this case the program will work keeping only the first input but, is there a way to check how many characters the user inputs in cin in order to print an appropriate message?

for example, if the input is `ab` it will print something like "Please type only one character".

Comment: What is the problem? One cin will take only one character input. If you want to enter many character make it as char array or try loops .

Comment: `cin<<c;` Not gonna work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting the number of characters in standard input after a cin has been executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242078/counting-the-number-of-characters-in-standard-input-after-a-cin-has-been-execute)

Answer (score 4):

Read a `std::string` and validate:

```
 while(condition){
     std::string s;
     std::cin >> s;
     if (s.length() != 1){
         // oops - make sure s[0] is not taken
     }
     c = s[0];

     // do stuff         
  }
```

Comment: `std::string::empty` instead of comparing is preferable

Comment: @Sugar: Unless you want to check if the string is a specific length other than zero ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is `std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()` which will tell you how many chars are still in `std::cin` buffer. If you are going to read just 1 char, and enter 1 char, the result would be 1, because of unread `\n`. So keep this in mind when calculating.

```
#include <iostream> 

int main()
{
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;
    std::cout << "cin still contains " << std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail() << " chars" << std::endl;
}
```